# Extract Headers from the first column

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, transformation

I have a scenario in which I am attempting to load a text file into Power Query. The first cell of the first column contains the column names that I need to use as headers.

How can I split the cell value by delimiter and use the resulting values as column names in Power Query?

I have imported the file into the power query.

Thank you!
[Image](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/image/serverpage/image-id/902728i904AF93B3956A209/image-dimensions/2000?v=v2&px=-1)
[Image 2](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/image/serverpage/image-id/902731iC4A8F9E6E75BC828/image-dimensions/2000?v=v2&px=-1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this in powerquery

```
let  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
NewColumnNames = Text.Split(Text.AfterDelimiter(Source{0}[#"#column1"],":"),","),
#"Rename"=Table.RenameColumns(Source,List.Zip({Table.ColumnNames(Source),NewColumnNames})),
#"Removed Top Rows" = Table.Skip(Rename,2)   
in #"Removed Top Rows"
```

[image]